# What is the time complexity of the following algorithm which finds the prime factors of a number?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

```
for (long i = 2; i <= number / i; i++) {
    while (number % i == 0) {
        number = number / i;
    }
}
```

What is be time complexity of above code, and how can I prove it?

Comment: Where is `number` coming from?

Comment: What kind of complexity are you looking for?

Comment: Do your own homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (long i = 2; i <= number / i; i++) {
    while (number % i == 0) {
        number = number / i;
    }
}
```

can be written as

```
for (long i = 2; i * i <= number; i++) {
    while (number % i == 0) {
        number = number / i;
    }
}
```

or

```
for (long i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++) {
    while (number % i == 0) {
        number = number / i;
    }
}
```

Therefore the outer loop has at most O(N<sup>0.5</sup>) iterations (it will have less iterations if `number` is not prime, since the inner loop would reduce the value of `number` in that case).

The total number of operations of all the iterations of the inner loops is the number of prime factors the original number has. The original number would have the highest number of prime factors if it's a power of 2 (i.e. all of its prime factors are 2), in which case it would have log<sub>2</sub>N dividers.

Since log<sub>2</sub>N < N<sup>0.5</sup> for most values of N, the total running time is O(N<sup>0.5</sup>).

Answer (score 1):

For a number like (2^m)(3^n)(5^o)...

The time complexity will be O(m+n+...) or (sum of the highest powers of prime factors of the number)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's O(n) if the number is prime

Comment: And what if it isn't?